# O que acontece quando a chave de assinatura expira?

Tags: android

Tenho lido que quando a chave de assinatura da aplicação expira não podemos mais atualizar nossa aplicação no *Google Play*.

A recomendação do [Google](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#studio) é que essa chave tenha uma data de validade de pelo menos 25 anos.

Levando isto em consideração, tenho uma chave que irá expirar em 2033. Pode ser que até lá minhas aplicações nem mais sejam utilizadas.

Tenho assinado todos os aplicativos com a mesma chave, já que isso facilita algumas coisas. O que poderá acontecer quando a chave expirar? Será que poderei renovar e continuar atualizando minhas aplicações ou perderei elas, já que não é possível atualizá-las no Google Play?

Desde já agradeço!!!

Comment: 'Pode ser que até lá minhas aplicações nem mais sejam utilizadas'.
'O que poderá acontecer quando a chave expirar?'
Você está com dúvidas e sua preocupação é valida, pois sua aplicação pode persistir sim por mais de 25 anos você também.

Comment: Ou criar versoes novas das aplicações, por que não?

Comment: Mas para criar versões novas das aplicações eu necessito da chave de assinatura para publicá-las na Play Store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Daqui 25 Anos tenha certeza que a Google fará diversas melhorias à respeito da forma de disponibilizar uma aplicação, e com certeza os desenvolvedores não ficarão na mão. A tecnologia avança e será diferente em 2040, não se preocupe com essa questão, não é o momento de gastar esforço já que são 25 anos, até lá, você pode criar outro aplicativo com outra assinatura nova, mas mantendo sua proposta no aplicativo. São inúmeras alternativas, então fique tranquilo em relação à isso.

Comment: Sim, concordo que a tecnologia vai ser completamente diferente daqui 25 anos. Criar uma aplicação nova com nova assinatura não seria a melhor saída, já que com isso terei que fazer toda a divulgacão novamente e assim poderei perder usuários ativos.

Comment: Bom, a Google já disse que uma assinatura expirada é assinatura expirada, então não tem como atualizar suas aplicações. A Solução é você que vai decidir, eu mostrei possibilidades. Não tem como ligar na Google e pedir para eles modificarem sua validade, não nesse momento.

Comment: Será que daqui 25 anos, terá algum Android que irá rodar um App que você fez hoje?

Comment: Interessante colocação. Tentei explicar em minha resposta que em 25 anos tudo que existe hoje será diferente em termos de software e hardware. Vamos torcer para uma resposta mais clara, para que não seja uma pergunta órfã mesmo tendo uma resposta condizente.

Comment: Concordo com a posição de todos vcs. Eu só queria saber a opinião de vcs e tinha dúvida se eu mantinha a chave atual ou se eu fazia uma nova com mais tempo de duração. Vcs lembram a data de expiração da chave de vcs? eu vou manter essa atual, se em 2033 o cenário se manter eu brigo pra renovar essa chave, rsrsrsrs. Bem, eu vou marcar essa resposta como a correta, mas se outras pessoas tiverem uma resposta mais clara pode deixar aqui.